# Odd character in HTML

Tags: html, encoding, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In some browsers is showing a strange character in HTML

### .cshtml

```
<h3>Cadastre seu currículo e faça parte da equipe Let’s Go.</h3>
```

### Generated HTML

[image: Odd character]

[Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA6I1.png)

### Metas

```
<meta name="title" content="Let's Go Festas" />
<meta name="url" content="http://letsgofestas.com.br" />
<meta name="description" content="isto é um teste" />
<meta name="keywords" content="teste" />
<meta name="charset" content="ISO-8859-1" />
<meta name="autor" content="Bind Solution" />
<meta name="company" content="Let's Go Festas" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="10" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" /> 
<meta name="googlebot" content="all" /> 
<meta name="classification" content="Internet" /> 
<meta name="publisher" content="Bind Solution" /> 
<meta name="copyright" content="Bind Solution" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**NOTE: ** In chrome for example , this does not occur!

Comment: You are sending those charachters to the browser (as can be seen from firebug) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those characters are utf-8 or more likely strays but your character encoding is iso-8859. You are showing both encodings in the head. Change it to utf-8 and/or remove those characters. I think those are strays, though.

Comment: I made the necessary changes, but still the problem remains `<meta name="charset" content="utf-8" />` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa - Can't look now but did you remove the stray characters themselves? Or are they not stray?

Comment: I managed to solve, just delete and re-wrote the phrase.
As the page text was copied from an external tool, it seems, he copied this code together.
When editing text, the code disappeared.

Comment: Yep. So a copy/paste of the stray characters. Sometimes this can happen with text editors inserting utf byte-order-mark unexpectedly which gives encoded characters at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue in a very specific circumstance: when I copied/pasted text out of MS Word into Wordpress. I don't know what system you're using - but, what I found had to happen to fix it:

Let's say your sentence is "See Jane [WEIRD CHARACTER]Run."

I literally had to go in and delete "e R" in the middle of the sentence, then manually type that back in. Odd, I know. But there seemed to be an odd space character that just got stuck in there.

Answer (score 0):

Run your site through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and see if it catches any enconding issues, you might have enconding issues or your document might be saved as something other than UTF-8 (such as BOM UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once and found that in addition to the meta tags, I had to set the response header as well. I don't know what language you're using, but in Java, it is something like this: `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`